# Velocity of Collision2D collider/rigidbody doesn't have velocity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

To start off I'm a beginner just trying to learn Unity, I'm just trying to create a Pong game.

Trying to access the velocity of a moving player object when the ball collides with the player. Tried to pass in the actual player object as a RigidBody2D and as it's BoxCollider but keep getting just empty velocities with the player movement being as below:

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(MoveUp)) {
        var move = new Vector2(0, 1) * Speed;
        rb.velocity = move;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(MoveDown))
    {
        var move = new Vector2(0, -1) * Speed;
        rb.velocity = move;
    }
    else
    {
        var move = new Vector2(0, -1) * 0;
        rb.velocity = move;
    }
}
```

And the collision being handled as below:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    if (collision.collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        var playerVel = collision.rigidbody.velocity;
        var playerColVel = collision.collider.attachedRigidbody.velocity;
    }
}
```

Both these velocity variables return (0,0) along with their magnitude also being (0,0).

I am trying to follow a tutorial, but the tutorial is years old and I'm wondering has something changed to how to setup velocity or am I missing something?

Comment: If the objects have collided have they stopped? Have you tried collision.relativeVelocity? Resource: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-relativeVelocity.html

Comment: @dgates82 this just gives me the velocity of the ball going into the player, not the velocity of the actual player. However your statement about have they stopped may be onto something, as I removed the else and now it has velocity, because it's removing the speed when the button is up. But even when pressing the key continually till the breakpoint it doesn't keep the velocity. So I guess my question now is how to stop the player without it then causing the collision to lose the velocity, without tracking when the key comes up as that doesn't work either.

Comment: What it you use a variable on the player script to track the "last velocity"? If you need it in the ball's on collision you can grab a reference to the player script from there

Comment: I did try this previously but didn't get the right response, I think I've got a better result by completely separating the stop from the go which then doesn't just stop it straight away. So think it's good for now, probably could be better but I'm still learning so, thanks for the help though! :)

Answer (score 0):

The way of collision detection has changed a little in the latest version of unity. Here is the code that I use -

public PlayerMovement movement;
public GAME_MANAGER GameManager;

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstalce")
    {
        // you need to make the ball bounce like velocity += 2f;
    }

    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Side Obstacles")
    {
        // here also you have to write what will be the action after the ball hit the paddle    
        FindObjectOfType<GAME_MANAGER>().IncreaseRightScore();
    }

}
```

If you want more in-depth information, you can follow this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAB64vfbrhI

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this via removing the stop and separating out the code for when the button is released. This causes the player to have it's y velocity properly.